# Lua Get/Set Metatable

Tags: lua, metatable

```lua
local ents = {
  GetLocalPlayer = function()
  
    local tbl = {
      localplayer = {"Ava", "1", {213,234,234}},
      
      GetIndex = function(self)
        return self.localplayer[2]
      end,
    }
    setmetatable(tbl, getmetatable(tbl.localplayer))
    return tbl
  end
}

local function main()
  print(ents.GetLocalPlayer()[2])
end
```

`main()` print returns nil. If I was to do `ents.GetLocalPlayer():GetIndex()` however, it returns 1.

The idea is to have the default return value to be localplayer if I don't do things such as `GetIndex()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table has no default metatable, which is why your `getmetatable` call returns nil. In order to do anything, the second argument to `setmetatable` must be a table that has at least one metamethod. (`__index` is the most common metamethod.)

The solution is to change `getmetatable(tbl.localplayer)` to `{__index = tbl.localplayer}`.